# Bootstrap 4.4 Navbar Collapsed Hamburger Icon Not Visible But Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Bootstrap Navbar working properly in collapsed mode on smaller screen sizes, but the hamburger icon is not showing up in the navbar.
Here is my code for the navbar. Please help me out.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <h2>PPDC</h2>
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <!-- other tags, ul, li and closing tags below -->
```

Comment: The icon appears in the demo above. Please revise it as needed to show your problem.

Comment: It has a media query, which sets display as `none` after for screens larger than 992px` 
`@media (min-width: 992px)
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: @isherwood didn't work for me when I expaneded the snippet. Edit: When I make the result full page

Comment: That's not what your question says. Please revise to be more clear. Also include enough markup so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you messing some **css** or **js** of Bootstrap cdn's so,
go with this code it's working fine.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```